Is there significance to the "smallest possible value for the busy beaver"
I'm aware some of the premises of the question might be wrong, please correct me if so.
For high enough $n$, the value of the busy beaver function at $n$, $BB(n)$ cannot be decided and there is some $p$ such that for any $k \geq p$, the proposition $BB(n) = k$ is independent of $ZFC$ (or should it be a $>$ instead of a $=$? I don't think it changes my reasoning if so, but please tell me).
In that case, is there significance to the smallest number $p$ for which that is the case?
Intuitively, I feel enclined to understand that as to be the "true" value of $BB(n)$.
Here's my reasoning, assume all machines mentioned are $n$ states, have 2 symbols $1$ and $0$, and start on a blank tape:

There are only finitely many machines that can be proven to stop (there are indeed finitely machines at all).
Since those machines all write a number of $1$ then stop, and there are finitely many of them, one of them writes the maximum number $q$ of $1$ among machines that can be proven to stop.
This proves $BB(n) \geq q$, and thus for any $k \leq q$,  disproves $BB(n) = k$.
No machine can be proven to halt after writing a larger number of $1$ on the tape.
This implies that any machine that does write more $1$ has to halt in a non-standard number of steps, or its could otherwise be proven to halt.
So, $q$ should be the $p$ mentioned earlier, ie the smallest number such that $BB(n) = p$ is independent of $ZFC$.

As such, there is only one "true" candidate machine for the Busy Beaver at $n$, as all other candidates not only cannot be proven to halt, but wouldn't even halt in a standard number of steps and thus aren't "truly" halting, at least not in a normal sense of taking a (truly) finite number of steps from the first step that can (technically) be reproduced by just running the machine with a pen and paper.
Is this intuition correct? It does feel correct, but in my (dilettante) contact with the topic, I don't remember having read anything mentioning that.

"In that case, is there significance to the largest number  for which that is the case?" There is no $m$ in the preceding paragraph... (also, largest?) do you mean "smallest number $p$ for which that is the case", right? Similarly several other ambiguous and confusing uses of variables in the text below. Best I can tell, you are asking "is the busy beaver machine the busiest machine that we can prove halts (as opposed to just the busiest machine that halts)?" To which the answer is yes, provided the proof system is arithmetically sound (since if a machine halts, that can be proven).

@spaceisdarkgreen indeed I meant "smallest number $p$ for which that is the case", errors from trying to rephrase stuff multiple times, then missed while rereading. You got the gist of my question right. Correcting that, and I'll try to make the text clearer next morning.

Note to everybody: If this question sounds confused, it's because the idea that e.g. BB$(745)$ is independent of ZFC is so damned confusing!

Any reasonable proof system will prove a given halting Turing machine halts, just by "following the computation line by line". A danger is that maybe it will incorrectly prove that a non-halting machine halts, but presumably $\sf ZFC$ is correct about things it proves of this nature (i.e. $\sf ZFC$ is arithmetically sound), so under that assumption,$^*$ a machine halts if and only if $\sf ZFC$ proves it halts. So your assertion is correct: the busy beaver machine for $n$ states is the most productive $n$-state machine that can be proven to halt.
Where the independence of the busy beaver problem comes up is on the other side, when we consider which machines $\sf ZFC$ can prove do not halt. If there are machines that do not halt, but $\sf ZFC$ cannot prove they do not halt, then how can $\sf ZFC$ prove that the most productive machine is in fact that most productive? The simplest example (conceptually speaking) is that for some large $n$, there is an $n$-state machine that searches for a proof of contradiction in $\sf ZFC$, writing another $1$ to the output each step of the search, halting if it finds one. By the incompleteness theorem, $\sf ZFC$ can't prove this doesn't halt, nor prove any upper bound on its production in the case it does halt (since such an upper bound, combined with a brute force search up to that bound coming up empty, would establish that $\sf ZFC$ is consistent). Thus $\sf ZFC$ cannot prove the value of $\operatorname{BB}(n)$ is what it is, as doing so would prove such an upper bound.

$^*$This whole post assumes $\sf ZFC $ is arithmetically sound, which in particular implies it is consistent. Perhaps unsurprisingly, if we use an arithmetically unsound theory as our proof system, odd things can happen. For instance, for $T:=\sf ZFC + \lnot Con(ZFC)$ using the $n$-state Turing machine of our example in the second paragraph, we can see that for all natural numbers $k,$ $T\vdash \operatorname{BB}(n)>k.$
